# QAction shortcut unable to set space as a hotkey

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am preparing a simple gui using Qt, but I have got a problem with adding some shortcut to QAction item. I've got something like this:

```
QAction* playAction = new QAction(playIcon, "Play", this);
playAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::fromString("SPACE"));
```

But all that i recieve during compilation is:

> no matching function for call to ‘QAction::setShortcuts(QKeySequence)’ playAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::fromString("SPACE"));

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was a stupid mistake. Just:

```
playAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Space);
```

Instead of:

```
playAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::fromString("SPACE"));
```